# Manual Backup as Disk Image, timed out

Tags: macos, hard-drive, backup, disk-utility, big-sur

I have an old LaCie 2big Network 2, (directly via LAN, no extra network,) which doesn’t want to work with Time Machine on Big Sur. I just want to use it as a safety backup for an old Mac I want to sell.

Now, ideally it would be in a backup-style (compressed, encrypted) .dmg image, made via Disk Utility-> New Image -> Image from Folder (User-folder (all I need.. right?) Alternatively the whole HD.. same problem, tho)
First, I got some permission issues so I disabled csrutil.. Now, I get a “**Failed with status 60: timed out**” error. I still see the .dmg being created and increasing in size.. but eventually being deleted again..
EDIT: Trying to use hdiutil results in "**[DIHelperProxy(Thread) waitForHelperDone] timed out waiting for helper registration**". Does this sound like a bug? Or is it a HW problem?
Any ideas why this might be?

The only alternative I see is hard-copying the complete home-folder ‘raw’ to disk.. which just seems messy (and takes forever) :// any other/better ideas on how to do such a manual backup? (I’ve see that you can create an iso if you delete the user but I’m a bit scared.. anyone tried this on Big Sur beta?)

macOS Beta 7 (20A5374g)

Comment: I have exactly the same problem, no solution. :/ I tried using the commandline as well, same result. I can only guess it's a bug in the beta version.